# High availibility's test of fabirc-peer with mulit version

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Recently I'm studying hyperledger/fabric-peer.

And I test the setup of peers' network.

I find out that using these images from docker hub to setup the network,

**I cannot let peer reconnect the network.**

---

**The following is what i did.**

1. Get four PC. Install ubuntu server 16.04
2. Get docker 1.12.2 and docker-compose 1.9.0-rc1 .
3. wirte the docker-compose.yml

   version: '2'
   services:
     vp1:
       network_mode: host
       image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.0-preview
       ports:
        - "7050:7050"
        - "7051:7051"
        - "7052:7052"
        - "7053:7053"
       volumes:
        - ./patch:/opt/gopath/src/chaincode
       environment:
        - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
        - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:2375
        - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=192.168.1.101:7051
        - CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE=192.168.1.100:7051
        - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
        - CORE_PEER_ID=vp1
        - CORE_PEER_VALIDATOR_ENABLED=true
        - CORE_PEER_VALIDATOR_CONSENSUS_PLUGIN=pbft
       command: peer node start
4. Get the peer's image.

   I get three docker image.

   - hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.1-preview
   - hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.0-preview
   - hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-c6e56d6 // I get this with using vagrant and making peer not in docker hub.
5. docker-compose up, boot the four peer node
6. docker stop vp3
7. docker start vp3
8. I get the error ,**peer reconnecting error**

   in vp3, [peer] FSM error vp0:... duplicated    vp1...    vp2...
   in vp0,vp1,vp2, [peer] FSM error vp3:... duplicated
9. change the image, and I found that the three iamges has the same error

---

## So, my question, fabric-peer is truly complished now about peer reconnecting?

## How to solve the restarted peer reconnecting? reconnecting the network error , then the network just do CONSENSUS with three peer abandnoning the fourth.

---

P.S.

**using docker pause vp3 , and docker unpause vp3 ,**

**the network is still OK, but this make no sense.**

here is log.

```
Attaching to composetest_vp1_1, composetest_vp0_1
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.477 [peer] func1 -> INFO 001[0m Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.3:7051
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.478 [peer] func1 -> INFO 002[0m Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.3:7051
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.480 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 003[0m Security enabled status: false
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.480 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 005[0m Privacy enabled status: false
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.480 [eventhub_producer] start -> INFO 004[0m event processor started
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.933 [chaincode] NewChaincodeSupport -> INFO 006[0m Chaincode support using peerAddress: 172.17.0.3:7051
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.934 [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 007[0m system chaincode (noop,github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bddtests/syschaincode/noop) disabled
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.934 [state] loadConfig -> INFO 008[0m Loading configurations...
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.934 [state] loadConfig -> INFO 009[0m Configurations loaded. stateImplName=[buckettree], stateImplConfigs=map[numBuckets:%!s(int=1000003) maxGroupingAtEachLevel:%!s(int=5) bucketCacheSize:%!s(int=100)], deltaHistorySize=[500]
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.934 [state] NewState -> INFO 00a[0m Initializing state implementation [buckettree]
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.934 [buckettree] initConfig -> INFO 00b[0m configs passed during initialization = map[string]interface {}{"maxGroupingAtEachLevel":5, "bucketCacheSize":100, "numBuckets":1000003}
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.934 [buckettree] initConfig -> INFO 00c[0m Initializing bucket tree state implemetation with configurations &{maxGroupingAtEachLevel:5 lowestLevel:9 levelToNumBucketsMap:map[1:3 7:40001 5:1601 3:65 4:321 6:8001 2:13 0:1 9:1000003 8:200001] hashFunc:0xab3e40}
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.935 [buckettree] newBucketCache -> INFO 00d[0m Constructing bucket-cache with max bucket cache size = [100] MBs
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:21.967 [peer] func1 -> INFO 001[0m Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.2:7051
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.935 [buckettree] loadAllBucketNodesFromDB -> INFO 00e[0m Loaded buckets data in cache. Total buckets in DB = [0]. Total cache size:=0
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:21.968 [peer] func1 -> INFO 002[0m Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.2:7051
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.935 [genesis] func1 -> INFO 00f[0m Creating genesis block.
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:21.970 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 003[0m Security enabled status: false
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.937 [consensus/controller] NewConsenter -> INFO 010[0m Creating default consensus plugin (noops)
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:21.970 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 004[0m Privacy enabled status: false
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.937 [consensus/statetransfer] blockThread -> INFO 011[0m Validated blockchain to the genesis block
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:21.970 [eventhub_producer] start -> INFO 005[0m event processor started
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.938 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 012[0m NOOPS consensus type = *noops.Noops
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.880 [chaincode] NewChaincodeSupport -> INFO 006[0m Chaincode support using peerAddress: 172.17.0.2:7051
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.938 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 013[0m NOOPS block size = 500
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.881 [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 007[0m system chaincode (noop,github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bddtests/syschaincode/noop) disabled
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.938 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 014[0m NOOPS block wait = 1s
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.881 [state] loadConfig -> INFO 008[0m Loading configurations...
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.939 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 015[0m Starting peer with ID=name:"vp1" , network ID=dev, address=172.17.0.3:7051, rootnodes=vp0:7051, validator=true
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.882 [state] loadConfig -> INFO 009[0m Configurations loaded. stateImplName=[buckettree], stateImplConfigs=map[maxGroupingAtEachLevel:%!s(int=5) bucketCacheSize:%!s(int=100) numBuckets:%!s(int=1000003)], deltaHistorySize=[500]
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:52:23.939 [rest] StartOpenchainRESTServer -> INFO 016[0m Initializing the REST service on 0.0.0.0:7050, TLS is disabled.
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.882 [state] NewState -> INFO 00a[0m Initializing state implementation [buckettree]
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:06.774 [main] main -> INFO 017[0m Exiting.....
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.882 [buckettree] initConfig -> INFO 00b[0m configs passed during initialization = map[string]interface {}{"bucketCacheSize":100, "numBuckets":1000003, "maxGroupingAtEachLevel":5}
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.882 [buckettree] initConfig -> INFO 00c[0m Initializing bucket tree state implemetation with configurations &{maxGroupingAtEachLevel:5 lowestLevel:9 levelToNumBucketsMap:map[9:1000003 3:65 2:13 5:1601 4:321 7:40001 1:3 6:8001 0:1 8:200001] hashFunc:0xab3e40}
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.882 [buckettree] newBucketCache -> INFO 00d[0m Constructing bucket-cache with max bucket cache size = [100] MBs
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.882 [buckettree] loadAllBucketNodesFromDB -> INFO 00e[0m Loaded buckets data in cache. Total buckets in DB = [0]. Total cache size:=0
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.882 [genesis] func1 -> INFO 00f[0m Creating genesis block.
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.885 [consensus/statetransfer] blockThread -> INFO 010[0m Validated blockchain to the genesis block
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.885 [consensus/controller] NewConsenter -> INFO 011[0m Creating default consensus plugin (noops)
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.886 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 012[0m NOOPS consensus type = *noops.Noops
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.886 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 013[0m NOOPS block size = 500
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.886 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 014[0m NOOPS block wait = 1s
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.887 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 015[0m Starting peer with ID=name:"jdoe" , network ID=dev, address=172.17.0.2:7051, rootnodes=, validator=true
[36mvp1_1  |[0m terminated
[33mvp0_1  |[0m 10:52:22.887 [rest] StartOpenchainRESTServer -> INFO 016[0m Initializing the REST service on 0.0.0.0:7050, TLS is disabled.
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:39.474 [peer] func1 -> INFO 001[0m Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.3:7051
[33mvp0_1  |[0m [31m10:53:06.800 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 017[0m Error during Chat, stopping handler: stream error: code = 1 desc = "context canceled"
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:39.474 [peer] func1 -> INFO 002[0m Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.3:7051
[33mvp0_1  |[0m [33m10:53:10.888 [peer] ensureConnected -> WARN 018[0m Touch service indicates dropped connections, attempting to reconnect...
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:39.476 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 003[0m Security enabled status: false
[33mvp0_1  |[0m [31m10:53:13.888 [peer] chatWithPeer -> ERRO 019[0m Error creating connection to peer address 172.17.0.3:7051: grpc: timed out when dialing
[33mvp0_1  |[0m [33m10:53:16.888 [peer] ensureConnected -> WARN 01a[0m Touch service indicates dropped connections, attempting to reconnect...
[33mvp0_1  |[0m [31m10:53:19.888 [peer] chatWithPeer -> ERRO 01b[0m Error creating connection to peer address 172.17.0.3:7051: grpc: timed out when dialing
[33mvp0_1  |[0m [33m10:53:22.888 [peer] ensureConnected -> WARN 01c[0m Touch service indicates dropped connections, attempting to reconnect...
[33mvp0_1  |[0m [31m10:53:25.888 [peer] chatWithPeer -> ERRO 01d[0m Error creating connection to peer address 172.17.0.3:7051: grpc: timed out when dialing
[33mvp0_1  |[0m [33m10:53:28.888 [peer] ensureConnected -> WARN 01e[0m Touch service indicates dropped connections, attempting to reconnect...
[33mvp0_1  |[0m [31m10:53:31.888 [peer] chatWithPeer -> ERRO 01f[0m Error creating connection to peer address 172.17.0.3:7051: grpc: timed out when dialing
[33mvp0_1  |[0m [33m10:53:34.888 [peer] ensureConnected -> WARN 020[0m Touch service indicates dropped connections, attempting to reconnect...
[33mvp0_1  |[0m [31m10:53:37.888 [peer] chatWithPeer -> ERRO 021[0m Error creating connection to peer address 172.17.0.3:7051: grpc: timed out when dialing
[33mvp0_1  |[0m [31m10:53:40.012 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 022[0m Error handling message: Peer FSM failed while handling message (DISC_HELLO): current state: created, error: transition canceled with error: Error registering Handler: Duplicate Handler error: {name:"vp1"  172.17.0.3:7051 VALIDATOR }
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:39.476 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 004[0m Privacy enabled status: false
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:39.476 [eventhub_producer] start -> INFO 005[0m event processor started
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.003 [chaincode] NewChaincodeSupport -> INFO 006[0m Chaincode support using peerAddress: 172.17.0.3:7051
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.004 [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 007[0m system chaincode (noop,github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bddtests/syschaincode/noop) disabled
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.004 [state] loadConfig -> INFO 008[0m Loading configurations...
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.005 [state] loadConfig -> INFO 009[0m Configurations loaded. stateImplName=[buckettree], stateImplConfigs=map[bucketCacheSize:%!s(int=100) numBuckets:%!s(int=1000003) maxGroupingAtEachLevel:%!s(int=5)], deltaHistorySize=[500]
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.005 [state] NewState -> INFO 00a[0m Initializing state implementation [buckettree]
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.005 [buckettree] initConfig -> INFO 00b[0m configs passed during initialization = map[string]interface {}{"bucketCacheSize":100, "numBuckets":1000003, "maxGroupingAtEachLevel":5}
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.005 [buckettree] initConfig -> INFO 00c[0m Initializing bucket tree state implemetation with configurations &{maxGroupingAtEachLevel:5 lowestLevel:9 levelToNumBucketsMap:map[5:1601 4:321 8:200001 7:40001 9:1000003 2:13 1:3 0:1 6:8001 3:65] hashFunc:0xab3e40}
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.005 [buckettree] newBucketCache -> INFO 00d[0m Constructing bucket-cache with max bucket cache size = [100] MBs
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.005 [buckettree] loadAllBucketNodesFromDB -> INFO 00e[0m Loaded buckets data in cache. Total buckets in DB = [0]. Total cache size:=0
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.007 [consensus/controller] NewConsenter -> INFO 00f[0m Creating default consensus plugin (noops)
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.007 [consensus/statetransfer] blockThread -> INFO 010[0m Validated blockchain to the genesis block
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.008 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 011[0m NOOPS consensus type = *noops.Noops
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.008 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 012[0m NOOPS block size = 500
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.008 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 013[0m NOOPS block wait = 1s
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.009 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 014[0m Starting peer with ID=name:"vp1" , network ID=dev, address=172.17.0.3:7051, rootnodes=vp0:7051, validator=true
[36mvp1_1  |[0m 10:53:40.013 [rest] StartOpenchainRESTServer -> INFO 015[0m Initializing the REST service on 0.0.0.0:7050, TLS is disabled.
[36mvp1_1  |[0m [31m10:53:40.013 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 016[0m Error handling message: Peer FSM failed while handling message (DISC_HELLO): current state: created, error: transition canceled with error: Error registering Handler: Duplicate Handler error: {name:"jdoe"  172.17.0.2:7051 VALIDATOR }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398253/fabric-network-what-happens-when-a-downed-peer-connects-back-to-the-network

Answer (score 0):

If you are still developing with Fabric Hyperledger, there is now a 1.0 version which is a re-write from the old version you were on.  Here's the link to the documentation https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/   the tutorials are done well and good place to start.

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question.

Comment: V0.6 is no longer supported.  V1.0 is a completely new architecture. Very significant changes.    I wanted to ensure the person who asked the question to be aware.   I am new to SO.   what is the etiquette for older questions - that can't be addressed